# List group events using Facebook Graph API v3.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, events, access-token

I'm trying to export the events for a "closed" Facebook group using the Facebook graph API. However, I end up with an empty set:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I have registered as a Facebook developer and created an "app", so I am the administrator for the app. I have also created a "closed" Facebook group, with two events, where I am an administrator.

I select my app in the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), select "Get User Access Token" and give the permissions "user_events" and "user_managed_groups". (At one point, I selected all permissions, to no avail).

Querying the group object gives:

```
GET /v3.0/<group-id>

{
  "name": "Test",
  "privacy": "CLOSED",
  "id": "<group-id>"
}
```

So I know that I have the correct group ID. However, querying events gives an empty set:

```
GET /v3.0/<group-id>/events
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Trying to list my own events gives the same result (I have a number of "accepted" events on Facebook):

```
GET /v3.0/me/events

{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Have I missed something in my app setup? Have I done something wrong with the token?

edit: I have not done the app review. My goal is to read out some events for me and friends, not a business venture. Making the app 'live' is not a goal.

Comment: Have you successfully completed the app review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review ?

Comment: @Jannes Botis  Hmm, I have not. Could there be a way to test the functionality before a review (I. e. with dummy data?). I am doing this as an individual to get a list of some events, but the title "Apps that Require App Review, Business Verification, and Supplemental Terms" suggests that it might not be possible to continue as an individual :/

Comment: Can you test using the default "Graph API Explorer" Application and generate the user token with it instead of your own app? Also, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205689/facebook-graph-api-return-empty-page-events-7th-may-2018

Comment: That also returns an empty list. I looked at the linked issue and I also found a post in the Facebook Developer Community group, and it looks that these APIs are disabled for "normal developers".  https://m.facebook.com/groups/146797922030397?view=permalink&id=1761198367257003&_rdr

Answer (score 0):

It looks as of April 2018, Facebook does only provide the user_events permission to select partners.

Issue discussed on Facebook Developer Community group: https://m.facebook.com/groups/146797922030397?view=permalink&id=1761198367257003&_rdr

```
Lot's of talk about this. Try searching
the group. You need to be a select
partner to use groups API and if you are
posting this, most likely you will never
be a partner.
```