# Facebook Graph API return empty Page Events (7th May 2018)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am trying to get events data on a Facebook page by using [Page Events API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/) but I couldn't get anything

It just returned an empty data object

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

I understood that Facebook is changing their platform at the moment and going forward we need app review to access this API, but what confused me is that it also doesn't work in Graph API Explorer with the necessary permission(manage_pages) as well so that means even though I passed the app review and get all the permission I need, it still doesn't work?

Here is the link for Graph API Explorer

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=336446383116538%2Fevents%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v3.0

This makes me think that Facebook just shut down this API and don't know when it is gonna come back? Does anyone know what is going on here and will it work again in future?

Many thanks

This question is potentially duplicated with below

[Facebook Graph API does not return Page Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791977/facebook-graph-api-does-not-return-page-events)

[How can I get the events for a Facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825680/how-can-i-get-the-events-for-a-facebook-page)

Comment: Graph API Explorer is the same as you doing the request your self. There is nothing special with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But with Graph API Explorer I can get whatever permission I need and test it, right? So it suppose to work in this case, but I still got nothing.

Comment: You can get the same permissions in Graph API Explorer as you can using the API yourself